# How to move all images into one group in xcode

Tags: xcode

All images and header files are looking very confusing. So i want to separate all images and other files into different groups. Anyone please help me

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? It's a pretty straightforward operation. Can you describe what the specific problem is?

Comment: in my app bundle all files not aliened in proper way,i want to move those files into separate folder,i was done in Xcode itself move all images to one group but changes not applied in bundle.

Comment: @siva in Xcode you are not using the files on disk, but you are only changing the projects way of displaying the files. If you want to move the files as well you have to do with the Finder, but then you have to reconnect all references in Xcode again. I would recommend against changing the files on disk, thus

Comment: I'm still confused. You say "in my app bundle". Do you mean the application that Xcode is building for you? You don't usually have header files in a built application. Do you mean 1) your source files in the as displayed in Xcode, 2) your source files on disk, or 3) the various resources in you built product's bundle?

Comment: @user1118321 2)my source files on disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To organize your files on disk, simply make the folders you want to make in the Finder and drag the files to them. To do this, open the folder containing your `.xcodeproj` file in the Finder. Use Cmd-Shift-N to create a new folder or choose "New Folder" from the "File" menu. You'll be prompted to give the folder a name. You'll probably want to name it something like "Images" or "Headers". Once the folder is created, you can simply click on an image file and drag it to the "Images" folder (or whatever you named it). Repeat the process for any files you want to move.

Once you've done the above, the files may display as red in Xcode's Project Navigator. If that's the case, you need to select the file in Xcode's Project Navigator and show the "Utilities" pane (the right-most button in the toolbar opens and closes the Utilities pane). There are 2 tabs in the Utilities pane - the File Inspector and Quick Help. Click on the File Inspector. It should display the name of your file, the type, and the location. Next to the "Location" is an icon of a folder. Click on the folder and you'll be presented with a file navigation dialog. Navigate to the new location of the file and select it. Click the "Choose" button and the file will be re-connected in Xcode.

You may need to repeat the process for any files you moved into new folders.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can also use 'groups'. A kind of virtual directory structure.

Iu the left xcode column (the Navigator), right click and select 'group'